# Laravel 7 - email verification but no page "Verify your email address"

Tags: laravel, authentication

I've installed Laravel 7 with `auth` and followed the steps for "email verification".

I've changed `routes/web.php` with `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
and `app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php` with `$this->middleware(['auth','verified']);`
`User.php` has "use `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;"` ans the database is ok.

But when I create a new user, the system send me to "home" with the message "You are logged in!" not with the message "Verify your email address".

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the MustVerifyEmail to the User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{ 
}
```

Comment: class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail